# Area/Sector of a circle: A cow is tethered by a 100-ft rope to the inside corner of an L-shaped building

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A cow is tethered by a $100ft$ rope to the inside corner of an L-shaped building, as shown in the figure. Find the area that the cow can graze. (Let 
$a = 30 ft$, $b = 60 ft$, $c = 100 ft$, $d = 70 ft$, and $e = 60 ft$.
 Round your answer to the nearest whole number.)

If anyone could explain to me what to do to solve this that would be great! I think just explaining what the first step or two should be will be enough for me to understand the rest on my own (like a hint).

[image]

EDIT:

Did I make a mistake here?

$\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(40)^2$,

$\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(40)^2$,

$\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(10)^2$,

$\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(100)^2$

Comment: 30 and 70 are not radii for any of the quarter-circles.

Comment: These poor cows...

Answer (score 1):

There are four quarter circles of radius accessible for grazing for each area centered on a wall corner as you sketched.

$$ c,\, c-b,\, c-b-a , \,c-d. $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the area in the picture is divided into different quarters of circles; find the radius of each, use that to find each area, and then add them up.

For example, the radius of the quarter-circle on the bottom right is $c-d=30$ ft, so its area is $\frac 14 \pi r^2=\frac 14 \pi (30)^2= {900\pi \over 4}$ft$^2$

---

EDIT: The radii, from the bottom right anti-clockwise, should be $c-e=40, \, c=100, \, c-b=40, \,  c-(b+a)=100-90=10$ ft

Comment: Okay, so I got 225 pi, 400 pi, 400 pi, and 1225 pi. Added together and got 2,250 pi which is approximately 7,609 ft squared. It's still wrong though. Did I mess up?

Comment: How did you set it up? I mean, which are your radii?

Comment: $\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(30)^2$, $\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(40)^2$, $\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(40)^2$, $\frac{1}{4}*\pi*(70)^2$

Comment: That last one should be $\frac 14 \pi 30^2$, because you have $c-(a+b)$, not just $c-a$. Visualize the rope wrapping around the whole corner to see this.

Comment: Oh alright. So I got $1250\pi ft^2$ or ~3927 ft^2, but it is still wrong

Comment: Oh, whoops. typo. The last radius should be $c-(a+b)=100-90=10$, not 30, like I said before.

Comment: So you have $\pi/4(40^2+100^2+40^2+10^2)= \pi/4(13300)=3325\pi$

Comment: @coldnumber added anti-CW hope alright.

Comment: @Narasimham yes thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the light area on your picture (which is supposed to represent where the cow can graze), you'll notice it's made entirely of quarter-circles of different radii. You should take a while and think about why the shapes would be circles.

Since you know how to find the area of a circle, you know how to find the area of the quarter-circle. All you need to do is figure out how large each of the radii are for each circle.

Here's a hint on how to start: The largest quarter-circle has a radius equal to the length of the rope, clearly. Now, what makes the radius smaller for the other quarter-circles?